# Un canif suisse ?

Tags: étymologie

Est-ce que l'origine du mot canif est le mot anglais *knife*, qui serait prononcé par un francophone qui ne connaît pas du tout l'anglais (sans doute en lisant cela sur la boîte ou dans des publicités) ?

Comment: Je n'avais jamais pensé à ça… K-nife. Mais pourquoi un canif **suisse** ? Y a-t-il une raison pour que le titre précise qu'il est suisse alors que la question se pose sur le mot « canif » ?

Comment: Tout le monde sait qu'un canif, c'est un petit fien.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Le mot français *canif* ne vient pas de l'anglais mais le mot français *canif* et le mot anglais *knife* sont tous les deux issus d'une même racine.
L'ancien nordique *knifr* (« couteau ») a donné d'une part l'ancien bas francique *˚knif* d'où est issu le français *quenif* (1441) devenu *canif* (1611) ; d'autre part l'anglo-saxon tardif *cnif* (XIè siècle) qui a donné l'anglais *knife*.
(sources : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* et *OED*)

Answer (score 2):

D'après l'[étymologie de canif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/canif) (et en admettant que j'en comprenne toutes les abbréviations), le mot semble assez ancien que pour écarter l'hypothèse d'un emprunt à l'anglais.